# Google Maps API w/ error "uncaught referenceerror: system is not defined"

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, jsp, google-maps-api-3

I am currently developing a "uber" like web app and am working with the google maps api.

Right now I have a home.jsp page with the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">

    <title>Home Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        div.nav{
            text-align:right;
        }
        div.right{
            display:inline;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src=
    "https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geolocationmarker/src/geolocationmarker-compiled.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        var map;

        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 13
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), mapOptions);
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        map: map,
                        position: pos,
                        content: 'Current Location'
                    });
                    map.setCenter(pos);
                }, function() {
                    handleNoGeolocation(true);
                });
            } else {
                handleNoGeolocation(false);
            }
        }

        function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
            if (errorFlag) {
                var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
            } else {
                var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
            }
            var options = {
                map: map,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
                content: content
            };
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
            map.setCenter(options.position);
        }

        function codeAddress() {
            var addr = document.getElementById('destaddress').value;

            geo.geocode({
                'address': addr
            }, function(results, status) {
                console.error(status);
                if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    //map.setCenter(results[0].geometery.location);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: results[0].geometery.location
                    });
                    //marker.setPosition(results[0].geometery.location);
                    //marker.setMap(map);
                } else {
                    alert('Error: ' + status);
                }
            });
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            if (!navigator.geolocation) return;
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
                geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude,
                    pos.coords.longitude);
                geocoder.geocode({
                    'latLng': latlng
                }, function(results, status) {
                    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        $("#address").text(results[0].formatted_address);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <a href="home.jsp">Home</a> | <a href="Logout">Log Out</a>
    </div>

    <p>Welcome eric</p>

    <div id="googleMap" style="width:750px;height:500px;"></div><br>
    You are currently located at

    <div id="address" style="font-weight: bold;"></div><br>
    Enter Destination Address:

    <form>
        <input id="destaddress" size="100" type="text"> <input onclick=
        "codeAddress()" type="button" value="Go"> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This .jsp page displays a google map located at the users current address and also displays the users current address using the api's reverse geocoder.

I am also trying to allow the user to search by address (using the regular geocoder) to place a destination marker on the map displayed on the page.

I have looked at several examples of this, but for some reason I keep getting an error message: `Uncaught ReferenceError: system is not defined`

According to the error console this errors point to lines `codeAddress home.jsp:73` and `onclick home.jsp:117`.

I have searched around for a while, but I cannot find any results from a similar error.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that you are using java code in your JSP without scriptlet marker. Due this in generated HTML `System` is interpreted as a javascript object, causing the error.

That's your error:

```javascript
function codeAddress() {
    var addr = document.getElementById('destaddress').value;
    System.out.println(addr); // your error are here

    // ...
}
```

If you want to show the value of `addr` in the browser console, use like this:

```javascript
function codeAddress() {
    var addr = document.getElementById('destaddress').value;
    console.log(addr);

    // ...
}
```

Even so, after that, you will see other errors. For example, `geo` is also undefined.

The code below should work:

```javascript
var map;
var geo = new google.maps.Geocoder();

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 13
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), mapOptions);
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                map: map,
                position: pos,
                content: 'Current Location'
            });
            map.setCenter(pos);
        }, function() {
            handleNoGeolocation(true);
        });
    } else {
        handleNoGeolocation(false);
    }
}

function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
    if (errorFlag) {
        var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
    } else {
        var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
    }
    var options = {
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
        content: content
    };
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
    map.setCenter(options.position);
}

function codeAddress() {
    var addr = document.getElementById('destaddress').value;
    console.log(addr);
    geo.geocode({
        'address': addr
    }, function(results, status) {
        console.log(status);
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
        } else {
            alert('Error: ' + status);
        }
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply! The System.out was a silly mistake on my part, I know better, I must have just over looked it with my glazed over eyes last night. Your solution does fix the problem.  However, it still does not place the marker on the map like I intended.  I will look into it more unless you have any ideas from looking at the code. Either way I am sure I can figure it out. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes @AndrewMannikus, this code just run without errors. Add a new question if you can't make as you need, so we can help you.